# How to fill a FindDropdown with data from api in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

im newbie with flutter and i'm trying to fill this FindDropdown that i found with the data i get from api.

```
FindDropdown(
                        searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Buscar",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  new BorderSide(color: Constants.blackAudi),
                            )),
                        label: "Seleccione el Taller:",
                        labelVisible: true,
                        items: [_.talleres[0].nombre],
                        onChanged: (item) {
                          print(item);
                          countriesKey.currentState
                              ?.setSelectedItem(<String>[]);
                        },
                        showSearchBox: true,
                        showClearButton: true,
                        
                        titleStyle: TextStyle(color: Constants.blackAudi),
                      ),
```

As you can see in the items: part im using the call to my method, however i am only calling the first item and i need to get all of them.

**EDIT:**
tried using _.talleres.map((e) => e.nombre).toList()

but didnt worked either :(

i got this:

[image]

I appreciate any help you can give :)

Comment: make sure you are in a stateful widget.

Comment: thanks a lot changing it to stateful worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit-1:**

FindDropdown takes a builder if your list is not predefined you can use that builder to build up your list. you can find an example [here](https://github.com/davidsdearaujo/find_dropdown/tree/master/example#custom-layout-endpoint-example)

You can try the `map` function to get all the values and then convert it into a list, as shown below.

```dart
items: _.talleres.map( (e) => e.nombre ).toList()
```

Comment: tried ur method, and updated, thank you for the help :)